# Would the Ward Shield spell work on the Shield Cloak magic item all the time, or only when actively using the cloak as a shield?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, magic-items

The description of the [*Ward Shield*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/ward-shield/) spell says:

> With a touch, you enchant a shield and enable it to protect its wielder from hostile spells.
>
> The shield grants spell resistance 10 + your caster level against spells so long as the shield can be interposed between the wielder and the spell effect. A spell shield does not provide spell resistance against area effect spells such as fireball, but does provide a +5 bonus on Reflex saving throws against such spells.

The description of the [*Shield Cloak*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/c-d/cloak-shield/) magic item says:

> The wearer of this rough, gray cloak can, as a move action, grasp the garment’s edge and cause it to harden. The wearer can use the hardened edge it as if it were a masterwork light wooden shield. Using the cloak in this fashion imposes no armor check penalty, but does impose a 5% arcane spell failure chance. The edge of the cloak can be dropped and made pliant again as a free action. Shield enhancement bonuses and special abilities can be added to the cloak as if it were a masterwork shield.

Would *Ward Shield* work on the *Shield Cloak* all the time, or only when actively using the cloak as a shield?

I'm asking because I'm wondering if I have to re-apply the spell to the cloak every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my reading of both the spell and the magic item, it wouldn't be allowed because the magic item is technically a cloak which at times can act as a shield and the spell target is a shield. You could likely be allowed to bypass this by casting the spell while the cloak is acting like a shield. However since the cloak can gain shield enhancements and abilities I would also let the spell be cast on it even when not a shield.

What the item doesn't say is the extra shield abilities that can be added only function when being used as a shield, which is a restriction I would add if the spell was cast on it. So ONLY when the cloak was being used as a shield would the spell benefits take place, not when it was just acting as a cloak because it doesn't count as a shield at that point.

Also, the spell has a duration and no stated discharge, so it would last until its duration is finished or an effect removes it. Using the spells effect does not end it.

Comment: So while of course the cloak itself doesnt give a AC bonus while a cloak, the effect of the spell persists anytime i use it as a shield?

Comment: @Tazuto When the spell is cast, the duration starts, doesnt matter if its in cloak or shield form, then while in the shield it should be usable, but that is upto the game dm